# WPF Application does not seem to be receiving a response

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.7.2, asp.net-core-3.1

I currently have two separate projects, one is a WPF application with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and the other is a console application with ASP.NET Core 3.1. The console application used to be .NET 4.7.2 as well however I have just finished moving it to Core.

The WPF Application sends an object to the console application and the console application does some stuff with it and returns a response. My issue currently is that the WPF application successfully sends the object, the console application receives it and does what it needs, however when it sends the response, the WPF application just hangs and must be completely stopped. Here is the code for both:

WPF Application (was working perfectly fine before moving the console to core):

```
static async Task SendRequest(UploadDetails u)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(_clientUrl, u);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseLink = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseLink = responseLink.Replace("\"", "");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SUCCESSFUL UPLOAD"); //TODO: Add response
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage(responseLink));
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UNSUCCESSFUL UPLOAD"); //TODO: Add response
        }
    }
```

Console Application (even sends correct response with postman):

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public ActionResult Upload(UploadDetails data)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { _Uploader.Upload(data); });
            return Ok("Started");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return NotFound();                
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Console application startup logic.... Also if you  place a breakpoint on the "return OK" line does it ever get hit?

Comment: Also please show us the code that calls SendRequest

Comment: Send Request is just a standard method called like any other method. There isnt anything special about how it is called. Do note, it was working perfectly fine before I changed the console application to Core. Also which part of the startup logic? And yes, it returns OK correctly, I mentioned that it returns properly with postman @Darkonekt

Comment: I am not talking about postman..... I am asking if it hits the break point when called from the WPF application... Meaning does the request even gets sent at all... You can place a break point here  "if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)" and look at the response to see if it returns 404.  Also I do need to see the method that calls SendRequest since it is async it has to be called correctly or it can cause the application to hang due to deadlocks

Comment: And I need to see the whole startup logic... I want to see what kind of controller you are using... what your routing setup looks like etc.

Comment: I updated my answer with some information on how to call the SendRequest correctly inside a WPF click event.  The answer should apply to calling it from the main thread of a WPF application.  I showed two scenarios one that causes the hang you describe and one that does not.

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem with the deadlock when calling the async method?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it is hard to determine the actual problem....

But just by looking at the code provided I see one problem:

1. You are sending JSON yet your action is not inspecting the body.

So I would make one change:

1 Your parameter should have an attribute [FromBody] like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload([FromBody] UploadDetails data)
```

Also you have to make sure your HttpClient has the correct headers when initialized like this:

```
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

The last thing I can think of is that you are calling your async method wrong in the WPF application....

For example this would hang on the "await _client.PostAsJsonAsync....." line

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SendRequest(new UploadDetails {  }).Wait();
}
```

This would NOT hang:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await SendRequest(new UploadDetails {  });
}
```

The reason is that the first one would block the main thread and the second one would not.

But without the code that calls the SendRquest it is impossible to know.

Comment: It does already have [HttpPost], I just realised I missed adding it to the question. It is also already getting the info from the body successfully, postman proves it. I was testing with postman requests which are the exact same as what the WPF client sends and it was getting responses as expected, I have already mentioned this twice now. I also did mention that the WPF client sends the request successfully and the console application does do what it was expected to do. The only thing that is not working is that the WPF client hangs on the await _client.PostAsJsonAsync().

Comment: So I need to see the code that calls the SendRequest method. Also you are missing the [FromBody] attribute... And you have not told us what class does your controller inherit from....  To post a question on StackOverflow you need to post a fully reproduceable sample of the code... Not just the parts "you suspect" otherwise we cannot determine what the problem is. @BradE

Comment: Also you say that the "WPF Sends the request succesfully" so you should have no problem putting a break point at line "if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)" and at the  return "OK()" line.... Using the WPF NOT postman.  And see what happens.